# Reference named single cell ranges in another range to copy-paste

Tags: vba, excel, range

I would like to copy and paste specific columns of a data set (table) with this two features:

- data don't start in a known row
- the number of observations is unknown (so is the number of rows with data)

I used the find function to get the ranges of the first and last cells with data, but then I can't figure out how to reference them in the copy function. The following is an example of what I want to do:

```
Sub prueba_copy()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim sht3 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim FirstRow As Range

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name)
Set sht3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet3.Name)

Set FirstRow = sht.Cells.Find("TIPO DE USO", searchorder:=xlByRows,     LookAt:=xlPart) ' the result is range: F4

LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", after:=Cells(1, 2), searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'the result is: 9
```

`FirstRow` and `LastRow` are going to be used to reference the range to copy. I want to copy the data from `FirstRow` to the column of `FirstRow` (e.i. F) and the row of LastRow (e.i. 9), so the action would read range(F4:F9).copy

```
'copy paste
 sht.Range("FirstRow.address():Firstrow.addres().column" & LastRow).Copy sht3.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

I have tried many options to reference the ranges with no success. So, I would be really grateful for your help.

As I am new to this, I would also appreciate any suggestion of a good webpage to learn.

Thanks,

Gustavo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim f As range

Set f = Sheet1.Cells.Find("TIPO DE USO", searchorder:=xlByRows, LookAt:=xlPart)

If Not f Is Nothing Then
    Sheet1.Range(f, Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, f.Column).End(xlUp)).Copy _
                 Sheet3.Range("A1")
Else
    Msgbox "Header not found!"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for copy-paste:

```
sht.Range(Cells(FirstRow.Row, FirstRow.Column), Cells(LastRow, FirstRow.Column)).Copy sht3.Range("A1")
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you are doing by using a worksheet's object to declare a worksheet variable is cluttering up the code.  The exception would be to give the worksheet a more meaningful name, which you are not doing.

```
Dim Source As Range

With Sheet1
    Set Source = .Cells.Find("TIPO DE USO", searchorder:=xlByRows, LookAt:=xlPart)

    If Not Source Is Nothing Then
        .Range(Source, Source.EntireColumn.Rows(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy Sheet3.Range("A1")
    End If
End With
```